# User Role Capabilities for WordPress Gutenberg Blocks

Tags: user-roles, block-editor, capabilities

As I am switching from ACF to Gutenberg, I am looking for a possibilty to set specific capabilities for my users.

In my common projects, my clients and content managers usually have "Editor"-Accounts while the designers tend to get administrator roles. I do that to enable the designers to change pages' layouts while the others are restricted to only enter content in the predefined fields but not add any content or change it's structure.

To achieve this using Gutenberg I want to remove the Editor's capabilities to add, move or remove any of the blocks using the `$editor->remove_cap( '//capability' );`

However, I couldn't find any documentation about the capabilities inside Gutenberg.

Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The capabilities are not that fine grained. There isn't a separate capability for adding Blocks. Only whether or not a user is allowed to edit a page. If they can, then they can do whatever they want with blocks.